# Can functions return virtual objects?

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, polymorphism

I am modifying a code, by make a class A into a virtual class and adding two Classes C and B as derived classes.
I have another class D which originally has an vector of A as a member.  One of the functions in Class D has return type of A.  Since A is now a virtual base class, how do i modify this function so that it can return either B or C?

Comment: Please post the code you have so we can provide the best answer possible. If you have a vector<A>, then all members are of type A and not of derived class B, C or D. If you just have a function returning an A* you can overload that function to return a B* or a C*.

Comment: You cannot alter function's return type. It has to always return a reference to A (which can be either  an instance of B or C). Then you have dynamic_cast it, if you want to access functions that are not present in A as virtual ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create instances of an abstract class, but you can create pointers to abstract classes.  So, instead of a vector of A's, make it a vector of pointers (or even better, smart pointers) to A, like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec;
```

Your function declaration should look like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> FuncName(args);
```

Comment: You probably meant _"You can't create instances of a abstract class"_ There's no such thing like a _virtual class_.

Comment: Meant to say pure-virtual.  Thanks.

Comment: Only functions can be pure virtual, that doesn't apply for class. If a class contains pure virtual function declarations, it's called an _abstract class_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, thanks for pointing out my mistake and helping me improve my answer, instead of going for the downvote.  That is much more encouraging and productive.

Comment: You were lucky, it's my birthday today ;-) ... No, seriously I'll not downvote answers because of slightly misused terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Values in C++ have one type.

There are ways to achieve polymorphism (one variable holding multiple types) in C++ without using pointers, but they are tricky.

The easy way is to have your vector hold `std::unique_ptr<A>` and make sure `~A` is `virtual`.  Then you can store a `B*` or a `C*` in a `unique_ptr<A>`.

As copying a unique ptr is banned, you will have to make sure any such copies are turned into moves, or add a `virtual unique_ptr<A> clone()const=0` interface to `A`.

Functions that used to return `A` should now return `unique_ptr<A>`.

---

Fancier approaches exist.  You can create a value type that manually manages object lifetime, for exmaple, or a smart `value_ptr<?>` template that understands the `clone()` interface.

Alternatively, you can create a value type that has one type, but can polymorphically store more than one type within it.

To give you an idea of how complex the polymorphic value type plan is, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30933464/1774667) is a sketch of a value-type that can store multiple derived types of `A` via `poly<A,B,C>`.  It still requires using accessors to get at the `A` interface, and is only a rough sketch.  I include it here merely to say that the problem can be solved: I do not advise you to use this technique unless you have already proven there is a performance bottleneck here, and you have exhausted alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a pointer to the object and not the actual object.

And I suggest using smart pointers, if you use a recent compiler.